# Why do I get type error when using scipy.optimize.curve_fit to do a least squares fit test?

Tags: python, typeerror, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I'm trying to fit  a function using curve_fit from the scipy.optimize module. I keep getting the error message:

"TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars'.

```
frequency = []
for i in driven_period:
    frequency.append(2*math.pi*i**-1)
   
amplitude = []
for i in driven_height:
    amplitude.append(i-41.3)
   
def amplitude_func(omega, p, omega0, gamma):
    x=((p*omega0**2)/(math.sqrt((omega0**2-omega**2)**2+gamma**2*omega**2)))
    return x

parameters = sp.curve_fit(amplitude_func, frequency, amplitude)
p_fit = parameters[0][0]
omega0_fit = parameters[0][1]
gamma_fit = parameters[0][2]

fit=[]
for i in frequency:
    fit.append(amplitude_func(i, p_fit, w_fit, y_fit))

plt.scatter(frequency, amplitude)
plt.plot(frequency, fit)
```

I've tried this same code with a basic linear function and it worked, so I think the problem must be with the function amplitude_func, but I can't figure out what it is. I've tried printing at every stage, but I cant find where I have the mistake. Sorry if this is a silly question, I'm new to programming. Help appreciated.

Edit: more info. Error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [151], in <cell line: 27>()
     24     return (p*(omega)**2)/(math.sqrt((omega0)**2-(omega)**2)**2+(gamma)**2*(omega**2))
     26 # lorenzian least-squares fit
---> 27 amplitude_fit, amplitude_covariance = sp.curve_fit(amplitude_func, frequency, amplitude)
     28 p_fit = amplitude_fit[0]
     29 omega0_fit = amplitude_fit[1]

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py:789, in curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0, sigma, absolute_sigma, check_finite, bounds, method, jac, **kwargs)
    787 # Remove full_output from kwargs, otherwise we're passing it in twice.
    788 return_full = kwargs.pop('full_output', False)
--> 789 res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
    790 popt, pcov, infodict, errmsg, ier = res
    791 ysize = len(infodict['fvec'])

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py:410, in leastsq(func, x0, args, Dfun, full_output, col_deriv, ftol, xtol, gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    408 if not isinstance(args, tuple):
    409     args = (args,)
--> 410 shape, dtype = _check_func('leastsq', 'func', func, x0, args, n)
    411 m = shape[0]
    413 if n > m:

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py:24, in _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs, output_shape)
     22 def _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs,
     23                 output_shape=None):
---> 24     res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
     25     if (output_shape is not None) and (shape(res) != output_shape):
     26         if (output_shape[0] != 1):

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py:485, in _wrap_func.<locals>.func_wrapped(params)
    484 def func_wrapped(params):
--> 485     return func(xdata, *params) - ydata

Input In [151], in amplitude_func(omega, p, omega0, gamma)
     23 def amplitude_func(omega, p, omega0, gamma):
---> 24     return (p*(omega)**2)/(math.sqrt((omega0)**2-(omega)**2)**2+(gamma)**2*(omega**2))

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Arrays:

```
driven_period = [1.027, 0.949, 0.866, 0.806, 0.648, 0.917, 0.935, 1.404, 1.113, 0.887, 0.983]
driven_height = [43.1, 45.35, 43.7, 42.25, 41.3, 45.9, 45.7, 41.5, 42.25, 44.75, 44.0]
```

Comment: Which line causes the error? Could you provide the complete code with both driven arrays?

Comment: @PHagemann , just added some new info to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figuered it out:

Python seems to have trouble multiplying arrays ( ** operator as well as math library). Switching over to np for calculations works. Sadly I can’t explain in depth why :/

```
import math
import numpy as np

driven_period = [1.027, 0.949, 0.866, 0.806, 0.648, 0.917, 0.935, 1.404, 1.113, 0.887, 0.983]
driven_height = [43.1, 45.35, 43.7, 42.25, 41.3, 45.9, 45.7, 41.5, 42.25, 44.75, 44.0]

frequency = []
for i in driven_period:
    frequency.append(2*math.pi*i**-1)

amplitude = []
for i in driven_height:
    amplitude.append(i-41.3)

def amplitude_func(omega, p, omega0, gamma):
    #x=((p*omega0**2)/(math.sqrt((omega0**2-omega**2)**2+gamma**2*omega**2)))
    p1 = np.power(omega0,2)-np.power(omega,2)
    p2 = np.power(gamma*omega,2)
    return p*np.power(omega0,2) / (np.sqrt(p1+p2))
    
parameters = sp.curve_fit(amplitude_func, frequency, amplitude)
p_fit = parameters[0][0]
omega0_fit = parameters[0][1]
gamma_fit = parameters[0][2]

print(parameters)

fit=[]
for i in frequency:
    fit.append(amplitude_func(i, p_fit, omega0_fit, gamma_fit))
```

Right now I’m only having access to Python interpreter via ssh. So I can not ensure whether the plot and fit make sense or not.
Splitting the function to vars `p1` and `p2` was only for debugging purposes. It could be merged back together.